# How to access nested array object in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to display **"details"** array from the list array. How do I correctly access it using map() function?

With list.map() I am able to map first level items, but couldn't find a solution for second level of the array.

output can be as below:

1 John, 18, 180

2 Don, 20, 170

3 Mr White, 28, 170

Code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
    this.state = {
        list: [
        {
        id:1, 
        name:'John', 
        details: [
            {
                id:1, 
                age:18, 
                height:180
            }
        ]
        },

        {
        id:2,
        name:'Don',
        details: [
            {
                id:3, 
                age:20, 
                height:170
            }
        ]
        },
  
        {
        id:3,
        name:'Mr White', 
        details: [
            {
            id:3, 
            age:28, 
            height:190
            }
        ]
        }
        ],
      };
    }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.list.map((item1) => (
            <p key={item1.id}>{item1.id} {item1.name}</p>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default App;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest a `map` inside the first `map`

```
{this.state.list.map((item1) => (
    <>
        <p key={item1.id}>{item1.id} {item1.name}</p>
        {item1.details.map(detail => (
            <p>{detail.age} {detail.height}</p>
        ))}
    </>
))}
```

You need to wrap the element in `<></>` tags because you can only return one element from a shorthand function.

You may also want to rename `item1` to just item as it will represent the current item not only the first one (this is not necessary for the code to work but just a good idea)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the details array inside of the first map and map over it.
Something along those lines

https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-brook-p6wkj?file=/src/App.js